# How to post an array in node.js

Tags: node.js, pug

I wanna make a form to send to node.js something like:

```
{
    name: "John Snow",
    email: "john.snow@got.hbo.com",
    phones: [
        {number: "1xx123345567", type: "Home"}, // Winterfell
        {number: "1xx897654651", type: "Work"}  // the wall
    ]
}
```

I try

```
form
  input(name="name")
  input(name="email")
  input(name="phones[0].number")
  input(name="phones[0].type")
  input(name="phones[1].number")
  input(name="phones[1].type")
```

No success :/

Answer (score 0):

Create a JSON object for your array using JSON.stringify().

```
var userObj = {
    name: "John Snow",
    email: "john.snow@got.hbo.com",
    phones: [
        {number: "1xx123345567", type: "Home"}, // Winterfell
        {number: "1xx897654651", type: "Work"}  // the wall
    ]
}

var jsonUserObj = JSON.stringify(user);
```

Then you write this object to the http request you use for posting the data.

Detailed explanation here - http://tech.pro/tutorial/1091/posting-json-data-with-nodejs

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers, as they tend to go stale if the linked page changes or disappears. Instead, summarize the contents of the link in your answer, without plagiarizing the original source (use `> ` to quote sections if necessary, otherwise try to explain in your own words).